Is there a more efficient way to calculate the variance of a random variable given two sets of data?
Given two lists, one being the values of a random variable and the other being their corresponding probabilities, how can we calculate the variance of the random variable?
xi = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}

pi = {0.1, 0.01, 0.07, 0.02, 0.15, 0.05, 0.2, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05}

Here, the array xi contains the values of the random variable, and pi represents the probability values corresponding to the random variable. How can we determine the variance of the random variable?
The variance of a random variable can be calculated using the following formula:
$$ \text{Var}(X) = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2 $$
where $E[X]$ is the expected value of the random variable, and $E[X^2]$ is the expected value of the square of the random variable. These expectations can be calculated using the values of the random variable and their corresponding probabilities:
$$ E[X] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i x_i $$
$$ E[X^2] = \sum_{i=1}^{n} p_i x_i^2 $$
Using the formula above, you can calculate the variance. My method is as follows:
xi = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
pi = {0.1, 0.01, 0.07, 0.02, 0.15, 0.05, 0.2, 0.1, 0.25, 0.05};
EX = xi . pi
EX2 = (xi^2) . pi
var = EX2 - EX^2

Are there other efficient methods to calculate the variance of a random variable given all its values and corresponding probabilities?

What kinds of lists do you have that would require something "more efficient" than using the direct calculation?  Is that measure in terms of AbsoluteTiming ?  Might you mean "more robust" methods of calculation where there is less loss of precision?

d = EmpiricalDistribution[pi -> xi];
Variance[d]
(*    7.0019    *)

If you insist on doing it "by hand", I'd recommend to (1) make sure pi is normalized to 1, and (2) compute the variance as a deviation from the numerical mean: $V=\langle (x-\langle x\rangle)^2\rangle$, not $V=\langle x^2\rangle-\langle x\rangle^2$:
pin = Normalize[pi, Total];

μ = xi . pin
(*    6.41    *)

(xi - μ)^2 . pin
(*    7.0019    *)

